# How do you connect to a remote linux server (graphically) with Open Text Exceed

Tags: linux, exceed

I have a server which I need to connect to and run a graphical program on.  I know that you can do this with Open Text Exceed, but it's been years since I've done this and the last time I did it was on version 9.  Unfortunately I only have a license for version 14 now and have no idea how to do this.  Any ideas on how I can use Exceed to connect to my linux server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, Exceed is a generic X11 server for Windows.

The usual way to use X11 over the network is by forwarding it over SSH, the secure shell protocol. Most SSH clients support X11 forwarding; this includes PuTTY (*Connection - SSH - X11*) and SecureCRT. First ensure that the X11 server (Exceed) is running, then enable X11 forwarding in the SSH client, connect to the remote machine, and run your program.

The older, less secure way is to allow X11 connections to be made directly from the remote machine; again, connect over SSH, but set the `$DISPLAY` environment variable to your IP address followed by a `:` and the display number (usually zero). This obviously requires mucking with port forwarding (TCP ports starting with 6000 at display 0), and is much less secure.

Comment: While this is technically a correct answer it really didn't tell me how to use exceed to connect to the linux server.  There are a ton of different applications in Exceed (connection central, Connection Manager, Exceed, HostExplorer,etc).  It's not as simple as double clicking and running exceed.

Comment: @Daisetsu: Thanks for the information. All I know about Exceed is its X11 server part, and that was a _long_ time ago. :/